# Are the family of given nice functions $f\subset C^0(I,[0,1])$ equicontinuous?

Tags: continuity, compactness, uniform-convergence

The family of *continuous*, bounded (in $[0,1]$) functions $f\in\mathcal{F}$ are defined on a closed subset of real numbers $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
f(y) = \begin{cases} 0, &\hat{l}(y)<\rho  \\ \kappa(y), & \hat{l}(y)=\rho\\ 1, & \hat{l}(y)> \rho \end{cases}
\end{equation}

$\rho\in(0,1)$ is a real number, $\kappa$ is a function from $I$ to $[0,1]$ such that $f$ is still continuous, $\hat{l}$ is a positive function from a set of functions $\mathcal{L}$ on $I$, for which it is known that $\mu(\{y:\hat{l}(y)<\rho\})>0$, $\mu(\{y:\hat{l}(y)>\rho\})>0$ and $\mu(\{y:\hat{l}(y)=\rho\})>0$ for Lebesgue measure $\mu$.

> Question: Is the family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ equicontinuous?

It seems that $$||f||_\infty =\max_{y\in I} f(y)$$ is true and is equal to $1$. Since $f$ is bounded I would guess that $\mathcal{F}$ would be compact w.r.t. the infinity norm.

If $\mathcal{F}$ is compact, then it must be also equicontinuous but I am not sure if It  is really compact.

If the answer would be negative is it possible to take $\kappa$ as an increasing function of $l$ to get a positive answer for

\begin{equation}
\hat{l}(y) = \begin{cases} l(y)/a, &l(y)<a  \\ \rho, & a\leq l(y)\leq b\\ l(y)/b, & l(y)>b \end{cases}
\end{equation}

$a<1$, $b>1$ are some numbers and $l=g_1/g_0$ is the ratio of two non identical density functions on $I$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the definition of $\mathcal{F}$. Is it like $\mathcal{F} = \{ h(\kappa,l) | ... \}$, that is, for each $\kappa$ and $l$ with certain properties you have an $f$? Is it like $\mathcal{F} = \{ h(l) | ... \}$, that is, for each $l$ you select a $\kappa$?

Comment: Yes each $f$ is specified by $l$ and a suitable $\kappa$. We select some $l$ first and this will define the domain of $f$. Then we select some $\kappa$ for which $f$ will be continuos. Whenever we change $l$, and choose possibly another $\kappa$, I will have another $f$ which is another member of $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may misunderstand the definition of $\mathcal{F}$. But to me, it sounds like I can choose $\rho=1/4$ and

$$l(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x \in [0,1/4] \\
1/4 & x \in [1/4,3/4] \\
1/4 + (x-3/4) & x \in [3/4,1]
\end{cases}$$

Now on $[1/4,3/4]$ I can arbitrarily pick $\kappa$ as long as $\kappa(1/4)=0$ and $\kappa(3/4)=1$. But that means I can choose $\kappa$ as restricted to $[1/3,2/3]$ completely arbitrarily, and $C^0([1/3,2/3])$ is not equicontinuous.

But I think I misunderstand the definition, because under this interpretation $\| f \|_\infty$ can be arbitrarily large. (For example, with the $l$ above, the intermediate $\kappa$ can be $M(4x-1)+(1-M)(4x-1)(4x-2)/2$ for any $M>0$.) I think there is a hypothesis either implicit or not stated (perhaps that $f$ are increasing or something).

Comment: I think you meant $M(4x-1)+(1-2M)(4x-1)(4x-2)/2$ but I dont get how $||f||_\infty$ can be arbitrarily large because we have $f\in [0,1]$.

Comment: The way I understood the question, $\kappa$ could be any function which makes $f$ continuous. For the $l$ I chose, the other requirements only force $\kappa$ to be continuous and satisfy $\kappa(1/4)=0$ and $\kappa(3/4)=1$. There are functions with arbitrarily large sup norm with this property. (My example was supposed to be a quadratic interpolant of $(1/4,0),(1/2,M),(3/4,1)$.) It seems you added the boundedness restriction just recently.

Comment: thanks for the comment. The boundedness was at the title from the beginning. But not inside the question. I added it into the question recently because I thought it was the key point from the example you gave. With boundedness I think everything seems fine right?

Comment: With boundedness you can still use a sinusoid of arbitrarily large frequency passing through $(1/4,0)$ and $(3/4,1)$, so you will not have equicontinuity.

Comment: If we dont have equicontinuity then we can never have compactness because each imply one other. So, then, it seems boundedness and that all functions in the given set satisfy the infinity norm with $1$ are not enough to have a compact space. I have a book and a paper which claim the compactness. That is however written by engineers without a proof and continuity assumption on the functions. The interval $I$ was the whole real line, which I guess creates other problems even for restricted sets, i.e., convergence of the sequences in reals.

Comment: There is probably a simple hypothesis that you haven't mentioned here that fixes the problem. The most obvious choice seems to be that $\kappa$ is increasing. This doesn't do the job either, though. For example, with my $l$ you can make $\kappa(x)=(2(x-1/4))^n$.

Comment: Okay I edited with the maximum information I have but to be honest I dont have any hope that it can become compact or equicontinuous.

Comment: thank you very much once again for the answer.